# Capture groups of regex pattern in C using POSIX regex functions

Tags: c

source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

I'm trying to imitate the following 2 SQL queries in C. The first works; the second failed:

```sql
SELECT regexp_match('hello world test', 'world.{3}');   
SELECT regexp_match('foobarbequebaz', '(bar)(beque)');
```

---

```
#include<regex.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_MATCHES 1024
int main(void)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    char buff0[20];
    char buff[20];
    char buff1[20];
    char *sz1 = "hello world test";
    //char *sz2= "foobarbequebaz";
    char *pattern1 = "world.{3}";
    //char *pattern2 = "(bar)(beque)";
    regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex,pattern1,REG_EXTENDED);
    if(reti){
        fprintf(stderr,"could not compile\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex,sz1,MAX_MATCHES,matches,0);
    if(!reti){
        printf("szso=%d\n",matches[1].rm_so);
        printf("szeo=%d\n",matches[1].rm_eo);
        memcpy(buff0,sz1+matches[0].rm_so,matches[0].rm_eo-matches[0].rm_so);
        memcpy(buff,sz1+matches[1].rm_so,matches[1].rm_eo-matches[1].rm_so);
        memcpy(buff1,sz1+matches[2].rm_so,matches[2].rm_eo-matches[2].rm_so);
        printf("group0: %s\n",buff0);
        printf("group1: %s\n",buff);
        printf("group2: %s\n",buff1);
    }
    else if(reti == REG_NOMATCH){
        puts("No match");
    }
    else{
        regerror(reti,&regex,msgbuf,sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr,"Regex match failed: %s\n",msgbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    regfree(&regex);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

output

```
szso=3
szeo=11
group1: barbeque
```

expect two groups, so group1 only return `bar`.

---

Update to the question:

- `pattern2` match again `sz2` behavior as expected.
- However, if only if only one part of the pattern matches then
  `matches[0]` should be the same as `matches[1]`.
- So in this new context, should I expect `group0` is the same as `group1`?

Comment: Note that `memcpy()` gives you a byte array, not a string.  You can't reliably use `buff` in the `printf()` statement.  You could use `int i = 0; int len = matches[i].rm_eo - matches[i].rm_so; printf("group1 [%*.*s]\n", len, len, sz2);` or you could use `printf("group1 [%*.*s]\n", len, len, buff);` to print only the relevant portion of the data.  And note the comments from [nwellnhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956010/nwellnhof) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266708/15168) — which is a reason why I added the variable `i` into the mix: you can iterate over the matches.

Comment: You're using the POSIX regex functions such as [`regcomp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html).  That's relevant because there are many regex packages available.  You know from `regex.re_nsubs` how many parentheses (captures, groups) there are in the regex.  You specify how many of them you're interested in the call to `regexec()`.  You'll only get `regex.re_nsubs + 1` such matches to look at.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated the question. In this new context should I expect group1 is NULL?

Comment: Yes, since you didn't parenthesize anything, only `matches[0]` contains any relevant data — it matches the entire substring ("`world te`").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `memcpy()` gives you a byte array, not a string. You can't reliably use `buff` in the `printf()` statement without some extra work. You could use:

```
int i = 0;
int len = matches[i].rm_eo - matches[i].rm_so;
printf("group1 [%*.*s]\n", len, len, sz2);
```

or you could use:

```
printf("group1 [%*.*s]\n", len, len, buff);
```

to print only the relevant portion of the data. And note the comments from [nwellnhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956010/nwellnhof) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266708/15168) — which is a reason why I added the variable `i` into the mix: you can iterate over the matches.

This code works for me:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_MATCHES 10

int main(void)
{
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    char *sz1 = "hello world test";
    char *pattern1 = "world.{3}";
    regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES];

    /* Compile regular expression */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, pattern1, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (reti)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not compile\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Nsubs = %zu\n", regex.re_nsub);

    reti = regexec(&regex, sz1, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0);
    if (!reti)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= regex.re_nsub; i++)
        {
            char buff[20] = "";
            printf("szso[%zu]=%lld\n", i, matches[i].rm_so);
            printf("szeo[%zu]=%lld\n", i, matches[i].rm_eo);
            memcpy(buff, sz1 + matches[i].rm_so, matches[i].rm_eo - matches[i].rm_so);
            printf("group[%zu]: [%s]\n", i, buff);
        }
    }
    else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
        puts("No match");
    }
    else
    {
        regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    regfree(&regex);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It produces:

```
Nsubs = 0
szso[0]=6
szeo[0]=14
group[0]: [world te]
```

[Because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74266641/in-c-capture-groups-of-regex-pattern#comment131118305_74266641) there are no grouping parentheses in the regular expression, there are no subgroups — the only information you get is about the whole of the matched text.

If you used `pattern2` from the question as the regex, with the two parenthesized sub-expressions, you would get more data in the `matches` array when the data matches.

By zapping the entire `buff` array with nulls on each iteration, there's no problem with the copying not being null-terminated on this sample data.  You'd be wise to ensure that it doesn't overflow in real-life code.

If only one of the two parts of the regex matches (in `pattern2` in the question), you will get an error back from `regexec()` and may not rely on anything in the `matches` array.

Answer (score 1):

Read the man page. `matches[0]` contains the whole match, `matches[1]` the first parenthesized group, `matches[2]` the second, and so on.